# % in beginning of codes in SAS

Tags: sas

As part of my work, I am going through this SAS code. I have never worked on SAS before. Could anybody explain the usage of '%' in front of the SAS lines in the code below?

```
%if &i>0 %then %do;
```

or

```
%put ##### calling formula;
%formula();
```

Comment: There should also be a `%end;` to indicate where the block started by the `%do;` stops.

Answer (score 2):

`%` signs indicate macros or macro code. Macros in SAS are *similar* to functions in other programming languages, but not quite. You can treat them *like* functions though. They deal exclusively with text and only text.

The macro facility exists to handle more generalized problems. Things in SAS are done in PROCs and the DATA Step. Each PROC and DATA Step is like its own little self-contained environment - stuff that happens in there stays in there. The Macro facility gives you tools to do things like conditionally call PROCs, the DATA Step, or system options.

I highly recommend taking [one of the free training courses on SAS programming.](https://support.sas.com/edu/schedules.html?crs=PROG1&ctry=US) If you want to get a jump start on Macro language, [start with this free course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/sas-macro-language).

To help get you started, here's what this code is doing, line-by-line.

```
%if &i>0 %then %do;
```

If the macro variable, `i`, is greater than 1, run some code. All macro variables start with `&`. The value of the macro variable `i` can be reviewed by typing `%put &i`.

```
%put ##### calling formula;
```

`%put` writes a line to the log in open code. This is likely being used to help debug things.

```
%formula();
```

This is a macro function that holds some code and runs it.  It has no arguments. Macro functions are created with the following syntax:

```
%macro myMacro();
    <macro or SAS code here>;
%mend;
```

`%` is the key symbol to invoke a macro. If we wanted to invoke `myMacro`, we can do so by prefixing it with a `%`:

`%myMacro;`